# OpenLDAP Local configuration for Application Authentication

Tags: node.js, centos, openldap, freeipa

I have installed openLDAP on a Centos 7 server that is already running FreeIPA for user authentication. http://www.tecmint.com/setup-ldap-server-and-configure-client-authentication

The purpose of openLDAP is for a Nodejs application to manage users for the app. and will be running on separate server.

I can see that slapd is running (ps -ef | grep slapd):

```
ldap      1287     1  0 06:40 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h ldapi:/// ldap:///
```

So I was trying to change the defaults using the ldapadd command and I suspect to be connecting to the FreeIPA LDAP that is configured on the box (on some coammands using -x -h it is asking for a password which hasn't been set yet):

```
sudo ldapadd -H ldapi:/// -f ldaprootpasswd.ldif

SASL/GSS-SPNEGO authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
        additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate)
```

If I run an ldapsearch then I seem to be able to connect to openLDAP:

```
sudo ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -b "cn=config" "(olcRootDN=*)" olcSuffix olcRootDN olcRootPW -LLL -Q
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
olcSuffix: dc=my-domain,dc=com
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=co
```

I thought maybe that I could connect externally using a Windows LDAP tool but I get a connection error. I did confirm that the port is open and visible externally.

```
nmap -p 389 10.18.16.243

Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-28 11:25 GMT Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for 10.18.16.243
Host is up (0.00s latency).
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
389/tcp filtered ldap
MAC Address: BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:00 (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 19.92 seconds
```

I tried using -h instead of -H:

```
sudo ldapadd -a -x -h localhost -p 389 -D cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com -W -f ldaprootpasswd.ldif
```

This prompts me for a password but I have only just installed openLDAP and not set a password yet (olcRootPW is in the ldif file I am trying to apply).

Does anyone have experience with openLDAP for user authentication or have any ideas what config needs changing to get this up an running?

Answer (score 0):

The secret incantation was:

```
sudo ldapmodify -a -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ldaprootpasswd.ldif
```

Since "-a" forces add new entries when using ldapmodify this would be the same as above:

```
sudo ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ldaprootpasswd.ldif
```

"-Q" -- Enable SASL Quiet mode. Never prompt.

"-Y" -- Specify the SASL mechanism to be used for authentication. If it's not specified, the program will choose the best mechanism the server knows.